# How can I automatically change volume/GPS/wifi/etc settings based on time and location?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean

I put Jelly Bean on my Verizon Samsung Galaxy SIII using http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-10-m2.

I like the "Profiles" feature, with which I can set ringtone volume, GPS on/off, wifi on/off, etc for different scenarios (work, home, traveling, etc).

However, I'd prefer that my phone just "know" when and how to change profiles.  E.g. at certain times of day on certain days of the week, it should be Profile 1.  If I'm at location X, it should switch to Profile 2.

I figure this should be possible since it has a clock and geolocation abilities.  I just haven't figured out how.

Comment: Check apps like Llama and Tasker.

Comment: Just a note: Profiles is a Cyanogenmod feature, not a Jelly Bean feature.

Comment: Oh really? I could have sworn I heard about it as a Jelly Bean feature before I even knew about Cyanogenmod. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) (free!) can also do this for you, and some say it's better than Tasker.

- With Llama, you can configure certain "areas" that trigger "events" when you enter them, or leave them, or are in them.
- You can also trigger events by time of day, or combine areas and times.
- A trigger can change the sound profile but also turn other services on or off - for instance, it could turn off WiFi while you're neither home nor at work except during weekends.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and then install [Profile 4 Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.martinutils.profiletasker) which will allow you to manipulate your CM profiles via tasker.

Comment: Aw man... is there seriously not a free way to do it?  It's shocking to me that what I'm talking about isn't built in to all smart-phones.  I'll accept this answer if someone doesn't tell me a cheaper way.

Answer (score 1):

Another good app for changing the volume is [Audio Mode Switcher.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moleapps.audiomodeswitcher)

There you can do everything according to automatically switching the audio-profile in one App.
You can define a weekly schedules to switch to a given profile. You can schedule multiple start and end times (i.e. when you go to sleep etc.).

It also offers a calendar integration, where you can choose to switch to a certain mode at a defined event. These events can be chosen according to their calendar and/or keyword based - I think this is very useful i.e. I can mute the phone if the word "cinema" is in the title and mute at all events in my work-calendar.

Furthermore location-based switching is also possible.